# jquery ui autocomplete push button and display issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've got the following code:

```
function testSearch() {
    $(".searchfield").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ path('my_search') }}",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.label,
                            value: item.value
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $.each(ui, function (key, value) {
                window.location = "{{ path('my_show_product', {'productId': ''}) }}" + "/" + value

            });
        },
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            /* $.each(ui, function(key, value) {
                alert(key + " " + value);
            });*/
        },
    })
    $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        var a = $('<a>', {
            href: "{{ path('my_show_product', {'productId': ''}) }}" + "/" + item.value,
            text: item.label
        });

        var $li = $('<li></li>', {
            style: "width:100%"
        });

        return $li.append(a).data('item.autocomplete', item.value).appendTo(ul);
    };
}
```

my data is returned from a function, called by the `$.ajax` function above,  in this json format:

```
[ { label: 'test label', value: '1234' }, { label: 'test label1', value: '4567' } ]
```

the input field looks like:

```
<input type="text" class="searchfield" name="searchfield" value="Search for Products" />
```

So far, I can search for items and get results in the above format, displayed on the front end in a list. Each item references to a page http://mydomain/products/(value)

Currently, I get the following issue: if I search for something and the search list appears, I can navigate with my keyboard through the list, hit the enter button and get redirected to the proper page, but the full labels of each item I'm focusing, are not displayed in the input search field shown above.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT:
so i've tried to modify the code to the following:

```
function testSearch() {
$(".searchfield").autocomplete({
source:  function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ path('my_search') }}",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            term: request.term
        },
        success: function( data ) {

            response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                return {
                    label: item.label,
                    value: item.value
                }
            }));
        }
    });
},
minLength: 1,
select: function( event, ui ) {

    $.each(ui, function(key, value) {
      window.location = "{{ path('my_show_product', {'productId': ''}) }}"+"/" + value

        });
},

focus: function(event, ui){ 

    $('.ui-autocomplete-input').val(ui.item.label);
            $(this).val(ui.item.label);
    //alert($('#searchfield')[0].className);
    //alert(ui.item.label);
    //$(this).val($(ui.item).text());
//  $('.searchfield').val($(this).val(ui.item.label)); 

    }

})
$.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function(ul, item) {

var a = $('<a>', {
    href: "{{ path('my_show_product', {'productId': ''}) }}"+"/" + item.value,
    text: item.label
});

 var $li = $('<li></li>', {style:"width:100%"});

 return $li.append(a).data('item.autocomplete',  item).appendTo(ul);

};

}
```

but it seems that the response is making problems: if i leave:

```
response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                return {
                    label: item.label,
                    value: item.value
                }
            }));
```

than the text field get the "values" of each label, this is not what i want. if i change it to:

```
response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                return {
                    label: item.label,
                    value: item.label
                }
            }));
```

i see the labels inthe input field, but the link for each item is in the structure http://mydomain/(label)  and not http://mydomain/(value) .what i need is the latter one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not doing anything in the `focus` event.

If you want to so something specific then you can do it inside `focus` event otherwise just remove it from the option. Be default the plugin will take care of setting the highlighted value into `textbox` if you don't specify the `focus` event in the options.

```
    $(".searchfield").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ path('my_search') }}",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.label,
                            value: item.value
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $.each(ui, function (key, value) {
                window.location = "{{ path('my_show_product', {'productId': ''}) }}" + "/" + value

            });
        }
    })
```

Comment: hi, thank you. the problem ist that in the focus event i can access the label.. if i writ console.log(ui.item.label) it says undefined. if i remove the focus event, i can use the push down button, but i get nothing displayed in the "searchfield"

Comment: Yes, you can access the label. If you want to write your own logic to set the textbox value with this label then you should do it. If you just remove that setting from the options the plugin will take care of showing the highlighted value in the text box.

Comment: could it be, that the default behaviour of the plugin is "destroyed" when i'm doing the $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function (u.... stuff in my code? because even if i remove the focus event, i don't get any values showed in the text box, it just leaves blank

Comment: in my first comment it should be "can't access the label" instead of "can access the label"

Comment: I dont think so because renderitem will be used to just render the searched items in the list.

Comment: if i use: return $li.append(a).data('item.autocomplete', item).appendTo(ul);  i get the "values" into the textfield displayed but that's not what i want... if i use return $li.append(a).data('item.autocomplete', item.label).appendTo(ul); it leaves blank in the text field

Comment: That is because `ui.item` refers to focussed item, you cannot say `ui.item.label`.

Comment: what else can i say to get the textual representation? $(this).val() seems to be the right one. i thought this migth work:   $('searchfield').text($(this).val()); but somehow it's not in the focus event

Comment: Try this `focus: function(event, ui){ $(this).val($(ui.item).text()); }`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6938/discussion-between-ramo-and-shankarsangoli)

Comment: the solution was a mix from the jquery ui autocomplete remote data and custom data